# Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have a signup.html with this view: [signup view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auHq6.png)
[signup view 2 and activation view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcnGZ.png)

when user trying to create account after clicking in submit(signup) they should get a email which is tHis image:[verification email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOBZb.png)

but im getting this error:
[the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjpie.png)

Comment: Please do not add code or any text-based input as image. Most likely no one is going to click these links. To get better help edit your question via 'edit' and copy and paste relevant code snippets and errors directly into the question. Add code formatting to improve readability.